# fetching the current time and insert into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new to development section . I have developed a code for inserting the time of an employee by giving the pause / resume option. 
The problem i've been facing is I could able to retrieve only the page starting time and first time pausing after that while resuming the time is dispalying the page starting time but where as i need the resuming time . 
for ex : the page starting time is 1430389269247
and the page pausing time is 1430389301723
and the page resuming time is 1430389314550
and again when i give pause the time has to start from resuming time  1430389314550.
but instead i can get only starting time 1430389269247.

```
              $(document).ready(function()
{
var startTime = Date.now();
var pausedTime;
alert(""+startTime);
$('#btn_pause_resume').click(function () {
if ($(this).data('paused')==='false') 
{
//alert('Resumed...');
//$(this).data('paused', 'true');
resumedTime = Date.now();
var UrlToPass = 'action=pauseTime&pausedTime='+pausedTime+'&resumedTime='+startTime;
$.ajax({ // Send the credential values to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
type : 'POST',
data : UrlToPass,
url  : 'pauseTimer.php',
success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
if(responseText == 0){
//  window.location = 'index.html';
}
else if(responseText == 1){
         alert("Sucess");
//window.location = 'majorprocess.php';
}
else{
alert('Problem with sql query');
}
}
});
         } else {
         pausedTime = Date.now();
         alert('Paused...');
         //   alert(""+pausedTime);
          var UrlToPass = 'action=workTime&startTime='+startTime+'&pausedTime='+pausedTime;
$.ajax({ // Send the credential values to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
type : 'POST',
data : UrlToPass,
url  : 'workedTimer.php',
success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
if(responseText == 0){
//  window.location = 'index.html';
}
else if(responseText == 1){
          alert("Sucess");
//window.location = 'majorprocess.php';
}
else{
alert('Problem with sql query');
}
}
});
          $(this).data('paused', 'false');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should probably not pass the timestamp for the current time via URL in any case, but just use the SQL function the database itself provides for that … (And you should use a more appropriate data type, instead of storing the integer timestamp – for MySQL f.e., one of these: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your first **UrlToPass** you are putting *startTime* in place of *resumedTime*. Although I'm not fully certain, I think that is why your code is not working.